# smooth substitute for absolute value functions

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Can we use this approach?
for :
$$A[f]_c(x) = \frac{f(x)}{1+e^{-cf(x)}} - \frac{f}{1+e^{cf(x)}}$$
where $c$ is a constant. we have:
$$\lim_{c\to \infty} A[f]_c(x) = |f(x)|$$
why?
first we try to prove it for $f(x) = x$ :
$$\lim_{c\to \infty} A[x]_c(x) = \lim_{c\to \infty} \frac{x}{1+e^{-cx}} - \frac{x}{1+e^{cx}}$$
for $x > 0$ :
$$\lim_{c\to \infty} \frac{x}{1 + e^{cx}} = 0 \land \lim_{c\to \infty} \frac{x}{1 + e^{-cx}} = \frac{x}{1+0} = x \therefore \lim_{c\to \infty} A[x]_c(x) = x$$
and for $x < 0$:
$$\lim_{c\to \infty} \frac{x}{1 + e^{cx}} = \frac{x}{1+0} = x \land \lim_{c\to \infty} \frac{x}{1 + e^{-cx}} = 0 \therefore \lim_{c\to \infty} A[x]_c(x) = -x $$

and we can prove it easily for any $f(x)$ that $$|f(x)| \subset \lim_{c\to \infty} A[x]_c(x)$$ and :
$$\forall x \in D_f \Rightarrow \lim_{c\to \infty} A[f(x)]_c(x) = |f(x)| $$
i wanted to know if there is a method like this for other non-smooth functions? is there a general method for transforming non-smooth functions to smooth accurate functions like above?

Comment: Have you heard of the concept of an approximation to the identity?

Comment: no i have not yet